# "Благодаря вам" Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги

**Благодаря вам** мы смогли выстоять эти морозы, не сломаться и продолжать дежурства.

Answer (score 3):

> **Благодаря вам** мы смогли выстоять эти морозы, не сломаться и продолжать
>   дежурства.
>
> Нужна ли запятая?

Запятая не нужна. Но слово *выстоять* лучше заменить на, к примеру, *выдержать* или же применить предлог ***в:***

*Благодаря вам мы смогли выстоять **в** эти морозы...*

Answer (score 0):

Обороты  с *благодаря*, начинающие предложение, обычно не обособляются.

Answer (score 0):

**Благодаря вам** мы смогли выстоять эти морозы, не сломаться и продолжать дежурства (оборот не обособляется).

**Пояснение**

**Обороты с производным предлогом БЛАГОДАРЯ чаще не обособляются, но это не является обязательным правилом.** Распространенные обороты  (с подчеркнутым значением причины и в предложениях определенной структуры) **автор может обособить:**

(1) **Благодаря вам** я сейчас спокойно покачиваюсь в старом кожаном седле... [Василий Аксенов. Круглые сутки нон-стоп // «Новый Мир», 1976]

(2) **Благодаря этой серьёзной лингвистической и литературоведческой работе,** впервые стало возможным говорить о рождении жанра танка. [Новый подход к исследованию японской поэзии и ее переводу на русский язык (2002) // «Проблемы Дальнего Востока», 2002.12.30]